# Transform Flask REST API into Django app

Tags: python, django

I am struggling on porting my (functional) Flask REST API into a working Django APP. I have researched but could not find solution to my problem.

It is for a movie recommendation system (based on MovieLens dataset).
Basically I want to move from this architecture:
[Flask API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uulbQ.png) to this one: [Django app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBNEr.png)

The Flask API is quite straightforward and works well when I test it with Postman:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from movieEngine import MovieRecommender
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/prediction/<int:userId>',methods=['GET'])
def get(userId):
    result = recommendation_engine.predictInterest(userId)
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route('/add',methods=['POST'])
def add():
    userId = request.json['userId']
    movieId = request.json['movieId']
    rating = request.json['rating']
    result = recommendation_engine.addData(userId,movieId,rating)
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global recommendation_engine
    global database
    database = './data/RecommenderSystem.db'
    sqlconnector = sqlite3.connect(database,check_same_thread=False)
    recommendation_engine = MovieRecommender(sqlconnector)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In Django, I have already setup the main `Models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'User {:} rated movie {:} --> {:}/5 '.format(self.user,self.movie,self.rating)

class Recommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    top5 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Recommendation for user {:}'.format(self.user)
```

The value stored in the recommendation table is simply a string containing a list of 5 movie IDs.

**Any idea on how to turn this string into an actual list of 5 movie names?**
All suggestions and ideas will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: You should look into django rest framework. Also you ManyToManyField for storing top5. Not answering as i don't want to code it up.. :)

Comment: wrt/ the rest part, also check restless, which is really lightweight https://github.com/toastdriven/restless

Answer (score 0):

> The value stored in the recommendation table is simply a string containing a list of 5 movie IDs.

That's very bad design. You want an [ordered many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) between `User` and `Movie`.

> Any idea on how to turn this string into an actual list of 5 movie

cf above.

Comment: I understand that for the generic case, many-mnay relationship is to be preferred. However, I found in the Django docs something about [comma separated field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) which could be easier to manipulate since my engine always return exactly 5 movies.

Comment: Read about relational schema normalisation, there's quite some litterature on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have now modified my 'Models.py'

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    topmovies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)
```

So I have a many-many relationship |Recommendation|<=>|Movies|.
Later I will modify the engine to fill this recommendation table.

In the meantime, assuming the recommendation table is filled-up, how do you suggest I handle the request?
On the `urls.py` I know I will have to add something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
                ....,
                url(regex, someView),
            ]
```

but I am lost on how to actually use the user_id posted in the request to fetch the list of recommended movies.